# GAE Python: Suggestion for modeling

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Fellow Stackoverflowers

I have a question, since I'm not a database hero. I have the following models:

```
class Hardware(db.Model):
    title        = db.StringProperty()
    description  = db.TextProperty()
    visible      = db.BooleanProperty()
    reservations = db.ListProperty(db.Key)

class Reservation(db.Model):
    between      = db.DateProperty()
    until        = db.DateProperty()
    user         = db.UserProperty()
    item         = db.ReferenceProperty()
    active       = db.BooleanProperty()
    archive      = db.BooleanProperty()

class UserData(db.Model):
    user         = db.UserProperty()
    nickname     = db.StringProperty()
    admin        = db.BooleanProperty()
    locked       = db.BooleanProperty()
```

In a later stage I would like to see what reservations a user made. For that I wanted to have another ReferenceProperty in the Reservation Model. But I can't. I get an error then

```
DuplicatePropertyError: Class Model already has property reservation_set
```

And I can't user the UserProperty anymore since I need to make Reservations for other users then just mine.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving each ReferenceProperty a unique collection_name [Docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#ReferenceProperty)

Comment: As simple as that. Thank you very much.